# No weights change, only the bias of the last convnet?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

i got a one-file python game, where a pixel in the first array should hunt (on the same postion in his array) a pixel in the second array. I trained it now for hours and hours and the only thing changes in the neural net seemed to be the bias of the last convnet ? I think, mostly the weights should change and not so much the bias, or?  The code of this simple game is here: https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_tensorflow_game/blob/master/pixel_hunter_game/flobotics_game.py

And here i got pictures of the weights and biases in tensorboard

[image: weights and biases]

[image]

Comment: I had this problem using unnormalized data

Comment: Yes, normalize data and also include batch_norm layer. Otherwise you could have problems with the weights.

Comment: do you got a simple example for me ? do you mean with "normalize data" the batch_norm function  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100

Comment: what layer output needs to be normalized ? h_conv1 or h_pool1 ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? Can you share your solution,please ?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that batch_norm does not exist anymore, but there is batch_normalization ? would that be an correct implementation in my case ?

```
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer, conv_weights_1, strides=[1, 4, 4, 1], padding="SAME") + conv_biases_1)

#batch normalization
bn_mean, bn_variance = tf.nn.moments(h_conv1,[0,1,2])
bn_scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([32]))
bn_offset = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32]))
bn_epsilon = 1e-3
bn_conv1 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(h_conv1, bn_mean, bn_variance, bn_offset, bn_scale, bn_epsilon)

#h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer, conv_weights_1, strides=[1, 4, 4, 1], padding="SAME") + conv_biases_1)
#h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(bn_conv1)
```

Comment: hi @Maxim , how should i normalize data ? with batch_normalization ? i got no tf.nn.moments() value then ? thanks for help

Comment: i updated my code on https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_tensorflow_game/blob/master/pixel_hunter_game/flobotics_game.py  but the weights still dont change, only the bias of the last conv net ??